# What is the probability that the drawn ball is red?

Tags: probability

### Question

> A bag contains $4$ red and $6$ black balls. A ball is drawn at random from the bag, its colour is observed and this ball along with two additional balls of the same colour are returned to the bag. If now a ball is drawn at random from the bag, then what is the probability that this drawn ball is red?

### Answer

I thought it as a simple question where the sample space is $10+2=12$

While choosing required drawn ball as red ,it may be chosen from $4$ balls or from $6$ balls($4$ balls $+2$ balls for condition  **two additional balls of the same colour are returned to the bag**)

So my required probability becomes
$$\frac{4}{12}+\frac{6}{12}=\frac{10}{12}.$$
But my answer does not matches with any option.
Am i doing it wrong? Please help.

Comment: Your answer suggests that it is very likely that you will get a red.  Does that feel right?  You need to read up on conditional probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Consider two cases.

1) If the first picked ball is red (this happens with probability $4/10$) then, after that, the bag contains 6 red and 6 black balls. So the second picked ball is red with probability $6/12$.

2) If the first picked ball is black (this happens with probability $6/10$) then, after that, the bag contains 4 red and 8 black balls. So the second picked ball is red with probability $4/12$.

Comment: that is what i have done ! $\frac{4}{12}+\frac{6}{12}=\frac{10}{12}$ so $\frac{10}{12}$ is correct ?

Comment: No. You are not considering the fact that that the first case happens with probability 4/10 and the second one with probability 6/10. Note that following your approach the second drawn ball is black with probability $\frac{6}{12}+\frac{8}{12}>1$!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to condition on whether the first drawn ball was Red or Black. If it was Red, the ball configuration for the second turn is 6 Red and 6 Black. If it was Black, the ball configuration for the second turn in 4 Red and 8 Black. So, the required probability is (6/12)*(4/10) + (4/12)*(6/10) = 0.4.

Answer (score 1):

With $R$ - red, $B$ - black, $.R$ - second is red etc., note that

- $P(.R)=P(BR)+P(RR) = P(.R|B.)\cdot P(B.) + P(.R|R.)\cdot P(R.)$
  $$P(.R) = \frac{4}{12} \cdot \frac{6}{10} + \frac{6}{12} \cdot \frac{4}{10}= \frac{2}{5}$$